# как равномерно расположить кнопки по div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

как правильнее было бы добавлять эти кнопки?

```css
body {
            background: #f3f2f3;
            color: #000000;
            font-family: Trebuchet MS, Arial, Times New Roman;
            font-size: 12px;
}
 
#container {
            background: #FFFFFF;
            width: 80%;  margin: auto;
            height: 100%px;
}
 
#header {
            background: #838283;
            height: 5%;
            width: 100%;
}
 

 
#menu {
            background: #333333;
            float: left;
            width: 10%;
            height: 600px;
}
 
#canvas {
            background: #d2d033;
            float: left;
            width: 80%;
            height: 600px;
}
 
 #menu2 {
            background: #333333;
            float:right;
            width: 10%;
            height: 600px;
}
 
 

 #navigation {
  float:right;
            background: #ff22ff;
            width: 100%;
            height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="111.css" />
</head>
 
<body>
 
 <div id="container">
 <div id="header"> <a id="downloadLnk" download="img.jpg">download</a>
<a id="downloadLnk" download="img.jpg">download</a> 
<a id="downloadLnk" download="img.jpg">download</a>
<a id="downloadLnk" download="img.jpg">download</a> </div>

 <div id="menu"> 
 
<a id="downloadLnk" download="img.jpg">download</a>
<a id="downloadLnk" download="img.jpg">download</a> 
<a id="downloadLnk" download="img.jpg">download</a>

 </div>

 
 <canvas id="canvas" width="480" height="400";></canvas>

 <div id="menu2">
 <a id="downloadLnk" download="img.jpg">download</a>
<a id="downloadLnk" download="img.jpg">download</a> 
<a id="downloadLnk" download="img.jpg">download</a>
<a id="downloadLnk" download="img.jpg">download</a>
 </div>
 <div id="navigation">Блок навигации </div>
 
 </div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Информации действительно мало:

1. Раз в заголовке написано "равномерно", значит text-align должен быть justify. Тем не менее в примере ниже я добавил один блок, который выравнен по левому краю - чисто для наглядности =) Там же используется `<nav>`, - так теперь принято оборачивать элементы меню.
2. Раз ничего не сказано про поддержку браузеров, я позволил себе небольшой хак в виде использования флексбоксов, которые не поддерживаются в IE, ниже 11го.
3. В Вашем вопросе в стилях для контейнера указано `height: 100%px;`, что явно ошибка.

Итого имеем:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="header">
        <ul class="items">
            <li><a>First Link</a></li>
            <li><a>Second Link</a></li>
            <li><a>Third Link</a></li>
            <li><a>Fourth Link</a></li>
            <li><a>Fifth Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="menu">
        <nav>
            <a>First Link</a>
            <a>Second Link</a>
            <a>Third Link</a>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <canvas id="canvas" width="480" height="400";></canvas>

    <div class="menu2">
        <ul class="items">
            <li><a>First Link</a></li>
            <li><a>Second Link</a></li>
            <li><a>Third Link</a></li>
            <li><a>Fourth Link</a></li>
            <li><a>Fifth Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    background: yellow;
    width: 80%;  margin: auto;
    height: 100%px;
}
/* First block */
.header {
    text-align: justify;
    height: 8em;
    padding: 2em 5%;
    background: #2c3e50;
    color: #fff;
}
.header::after, .menu::after, .menu2::after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.items {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

/* Second and third blocks */
.menu, .menu2 {
    text-align: justify;
    height: 8em;
    padding: 2em 5%;
    background: #0023ab;
    color: #fff;
}
.menu nav {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: left;
}
.menu nav a{
    padding: 0 0.6em;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.menu nav a:last-child {
    padding-right: 0;
}
```